# React Native 'firebase.messaging().getToken()' is not called from 'RNFirebaseMessaging.java' class android in release apk

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-firebase

I am using react-native-firebase library for Firebase push-notifications in React native from Android Platfrom.

My code works perfect in debug apk but when i export my apk into release mode then **'firebase.messaging().getToken()'**  does'nt called from my android react-native-firebase library class **'RNFirebaseMessaging.java'**.

can anyone please suggest me why i am facing this issue and how to solve this problem.

Below is my code :

**MainApplication.java**

```
    package com.njrefresh;

    import android.app.Application;

    import com.RNFetchBlob.RNFetchBlobPackage;
    import com.dylanvann.fastimage.FastImageViewPackage;
    import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
    import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
    import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
    import com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage;
    import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;
    import com.github.alinz.reactnativewebviewbridge.WebViewBridgePackage;
    import com.github.xinthink.rnmk.ReactMaterialKitPackage;
    import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
    import com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions;
    import com.google.firebase.analytics.FirebaseAnalytics;
    import com.learnium.RNDeviceInfo.RNDeviceInfo;
    import com.oblador.vectoricons.VectorIconsPackage;

    import org.devio.rn.splashscreen.SplashScreenReactPackage;
    import org.wonday.pdf.RCTPdfView;

    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.List;

    import cl.json.RNSharePackage;
    import io.invertase.firebase.RNFirebasePackage;
    import io.invertase.firebase.analytics.RNFirebaseAnalyticsPackage;
    import io.invertase.firebase.instanceid.RNFirebaseInstanceIdPackage;
    import io.invertase.firebase.messaging.RNFirebaseMessagingPackage;
    import io.invertase.firebase.notifications.RNFirebaseNotificationsPackage;


    public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

        private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
            @Override
            public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
                return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
            }

            @Override
            protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
                return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
                        new MainReactPackage(),
                        new RNFirebaseNotificationsPackage(),
                        new RNFirebaseMessagingPackage(),
                        new RNFirebaseInstanceIdPackage(),
                        new RNFirebasePackage(),
                        new ReactMaterialKitPackage(),
                        new RNSharePackage(),
                        new WebViewBridgePackage(),
                        new FastImageViewPackage(),
                        new VectorIconsPackage(),
                        new SplashScreenReactPackage(),
                        new RCTPdfView(),
                        new RNFetchBlobPackage(),
                        new RNDeviceInfo(),
                        new RNFirebaseAnalyticsPackage(),
    //            new ReactNativePushNotificationPackage(),
                        new ModulusPackager()
                );
            }

            @Override
            protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
                return "index";
            }
        };
        private FirebaseAnalytics sAnalytics;

        @Override
        public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
            return mReactNativeHost;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();
            SoLoader.init(this, false);
            FirebaseApp.initializeApp(getApplicationContext(), new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                    .setProjectId(getString(R.string.fa_project_id))
                    .setDatabaseUrl(getString(R.string.fa_database_url))
                    .setApplicationId(getString(R.string.fa_app_id)) // Required for Analytics.
                    .setApiKey(getString(R.string.fa_api_key)) // Required for Auth.
                    .build(), FirebaseApp.DEFAULT_APP_NAME);
            getDefaultTracker();


            FirebaseApp.initializeApp(getApplicationContext(), new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                    .setProjectId(getString(R.string.fcm_project_id))
                    .setDatabaseUrl(getString(R.string.fcm_database_url))
                    .setApplicationId(getString(R.string.fcm_app_id))
                    .setApiKey(getString(R.string.fcm_api_key))
                    .build(), getString(R.string.fcm_instance_name));
        }

        protected boolean isDefaultFirebaseAppInitialized() {
            try {
                // try get
                return FirebaseApp.getInstance(FirebaseApp.DEFAULT_APP_NAME) != null;
                // catch illegal state exc
            } catch (IllegalStateException ise) {
                // on such case not initialized
                return false;
            }
        }

        synchronized public FirebaseAnalytics getDefaultTracker() {
            if (sAnalytics == null) {
                if (isDefaultFirebaseAppInitialized()) {
                    sAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);
                } else {

                }
            }
            return sAnalytics;
        }

    }
```

**RNFirebaseMessaging.java**

```
package io.invertase.firebase.messaging;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationManagerCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
import android.util.Log;

import com.facebook.react.bridge.Promise;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactMethod;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableMap;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableMapKeySetIterator;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.WritableMap;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId;
import com.google.firebase.iid.InstanceIdResult;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.annotation.Nonnull;

import io.invertase.firebase.Utils;

public class RNFirebaseMessaging extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {
  private static final String TAG = "RNFirebaseMessaging";
  private String token="NA";

  RNFirebaseMessaging(ReactApplicationContext context) {
    super(context);
    LocalBroadcastManager localBroadcastManager = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context);

    // Subscribe to message events
    localBroadcastManager.registerReceiver(
      new MessageReceiver(),
      new IntentFilter(RNFirebaseMessagingService.MESSAGE_EVENT)
    );

    // Subscribe to new token events
    localBroadcastManager.registerReceiver(
      new RefreshTokenReceiver(),
      new IntentFilter(RNFirebaseMessagingService.NEW_TOKEN_EVENT)
    );
  }

  @Override
  public String getName() {
    return "RNFirebaseMessaging";
  }

  @ReactMethod
  public void getToken(Promise promise) {
    Log.d(TAG, "HARISH LOG: secondary=>");
    try {
      FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance(FirebaseApp.getInstance("secondary")).getInstanceId()
              .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<InstanceIdResult> task) {
                  if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                    return;
                  }
                  token = task.getResult().getToken();
                  Log.d(TAG, "onCompleteToken: secondary=>"+token);
                }
              });
      promise.resolve(token);
    } catch (Throwable e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      promise.reject("messaging/fcm-token-error", e.getMessage());
    }
  }

  @ReactMethod
  public void deleteToken(Promise promise) {
    try {
      String senderId = FirebaseApp.getInstance().getOptions().getGcmSenderId();
      FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().deleteToken(senderId, FirebaseMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE);
      promise.resolve(null);
    } catch (Throwable e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      promise.reject("messaging/fcm-token-error", e.getMessage());
    }
  }

  @ReactMethod
  public void requestPermission(Promise promise) {
    Log.d(TAG, "requestPermission Harish");
    promise.resolve(null);
  }

  // Non Web SDK methods
  @ReactMethod
  public void hasPermission(Promise promise) {
    Boolean enabled = NotificationManagerCompat
      .from(getReactApplicationContext())
      .areNotificationsEnabled();
    promise.resolve(enabled);
  }

  @ReactMethod
  public void sendMessage(ReadableMap messageMap, Promise promise) {
    if (!messageMap.hasKey("to")) {
      promise.reject("messaging/invalid-message", "The supplied message is missing a 'to' field");
      return;
    }

    RemoteMessage.Builder mb = new RemoteMessage.Builder(messageMap.getString("to"));

    if (messageMap.hasKey("collapseKey")) {
      mb = mb.setCollapseKey(messageMap.getString("collapseKey"));
    }
    if (messageMap.hasKey("messageId")) {
      mb = mb.setMessageId(messageMap.getString("messageId"));
    }
    if (messageMap.hasKey("messageType")) {
      mb = mb.setMessageType(messageMap.getString("messageType"));
    }
    if (messageMap.hasKey("ttl")) {
      mb = mb.setTtl(messageMap.getInt("ttl"));
    }
    if (messageMap.hasKey("data")) {
      ReadableMap dataMap = messageMap.getMap("data");
      ReadableMapKeySetIterator iterator = dataMap.keySetIterator();
      while (iterator.hasNextKey()) {
        String key = iterator.nextKey();
        mb = mb.addData(key, dataMap.getString(key));
      }
    }

    FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().send(mb.build());

    // TODO: Listen to onMessageSent and onSendError for better feedback?
    promise.resolve(null);
  }

  @ReactMethod
  public void subscribeToTopic(String topic, final Promise promise) {
    FirebaseMessaging
      .getInstance()
      .subscribeToTopic(topic)
      .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@Nonnull Task<Void> task) {
          if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "subscribeToTopic:onComplete:success");
            promise.resolve(null);
          } else {
            Exception exception = task.getException();
            Log.e(TAG, "subscribeToTopic:onComplete:failure", exception);
            promise.reject(exception);
          }
        }
      });
  }

  @ReactMethod
  public void unsubscribeFromTopic(String topic, final Promise promise) {
    FirebaseMessaging
      .getInstance()
      .unsubscribeFromTopic(topic)
      .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@Nonnull Task<Void> task) {
          if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "unsubscribeFromTopic:onComplete:success");
            promise.resolve(null);
          } else {
            Exception exception = task.getException();
            Log.e(TAG, "unsubscribeFromTopic:onComplete:failure", exception);
            promise.reject(exception);
          }
        }
      });
  }

  private class MessageReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      if (getReactApplicationContext().hasActiveCatalystInstance()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Received new message");

        RemoteMessage message = intent.getParcelableExtra("message");
        WritableMap messageMap = MessagingSerializer.parseRemoteMessage(message);

        Utils.sendEvent(getReactApplicationContext(), "messaging_message_received", messageMap);
      }
    }
  }

  private class RefreshTokenReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      if (getReactApplicationContext().hasActiveCatalystInstance()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Received new messaging token.");
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
            FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance(FirebaseApp.getInstance("secondary")).getInstanceId()
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
                      @Override
                      public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<InstanceIdResult> task) {
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                          return;
                        }
                        token = task.getResult().getToken();
                        Log.d(TAG, "onCompleteToken: =>"+token);
                      }
                    });
            if (token != null) {
              Log.d(TAG, "Sending new messaging token event.");
              Utils.sendEvent(getReactApplicationContext(), "messaging_token_refreshed", token);
            }
          }
        });

        thread.start();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.njrefresh">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <permission
        android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:allowBackup="true"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:largeHeap="true">


        <provider
            android:name="com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.firebaseinitprovider"
            tools:node="remove" />

        <service android:name="io.invertase.firebase.messaging.RNFirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter android:priority="10" >
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <service android:name="io.invertase.firebase.messaging.RNFirebaseBackgroundMessagingService" />

        <receiver android:name="io.invertase.firebase.notifications.RNFirebaseNotificationReceiver"/>
        <receiver android:enabled="true" android:exported="true"  android:name="io.invertase.firebase.notifications.RNFirebaseNotificationsRebootReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
                <action android:name="com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            >
            <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="fcm.ACTION.HELLO" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>

        <service
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter android:priority="10" >
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
            android:value="refresh-channel"/>

        <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />

        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
componentDidMount = () => {
    this._checkPermission()
}

_checkPermission = async() => {
    const enabled = await firebase.messaging().hasPermission();
    if (enabled) {
        const device = await firebase.messaging().getToken()
        console.warn(device)
    }
    else this._getPermission() 
} 

_getPermission = async() => {
    firebase.messaging().requestPermission()
    .then(() => {
        this._checkPermission()
    })
    .catch(error => {
        // User has rejected permissions  
    });
}
```